# How to determine if a CPU is compatible to a mainboard - and vice versa

Tags: cpu, motherboard, processor-socket

I am planning to buy an **[Intel G4560](https://ark.intel.com/products/97143/Intel-Pentium-Processor-G4560-3M-Cache-3_50-GHz)** processor. My current motherboard is an **[ASUS P5QPL-AM](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5QPLAM/)**. I am not sure if the processor will fit into my motherboard.

I have only little knowledge about computer hardware, so my question is: how can one determine the compatibility between a certain CPU and any motherboard - and vice versa?

Comment: See [your motherboard's CPU support info on asus' website](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5QPLAM/HelpDesk_CPU/) for a list of supported CPUs. However, since your MoBo has a socket 775 and the g4560 needs a socket 1151 you won't even be able to install the CPU into the MoBo. So the limit here is not only the lack of support (software-wise), but also a physical incompatibility - which is quite good, considering that your motherboard would most likely just melt your CPU down.

Comment: actually how to determine how to choose right processor for a motherboard?what criterion to look for ?

Comment: added an answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not compatible.

As a rule if the socket is different it's almost-certainly NOT compatible*. If the socket is the same it may or may not be compatible. Motherboard vendors will generally publish a list of officially compatible CPUs on their website somewhere. Note that you may need a BIOS upgrade to use newer CPUs. Sometimes other CPUs in the same families but not on the official list may work, sometimes not.

The CPU support list for your motherboard is at https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5QPLAM/HelpDesk_CPU/ (thanks flolilolilo) It seems that what is officially supported depends on both the BIOS revision and the PCB revision (which should be printed on the board somewhere). I would guess from the list that 1.00G was the first PCB revision sold since nearly all the chips in the list require at least that revision (a few list PCB revision of "ALL" but they seem to be newer chips added tot he support list later).

It looks like the best CPU supported by your motherboard is the Q9650 which sells for about £50 used. Unfortunately this is now several years behind the state of the art and will have substantially lower performance than a modern part (see for example http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core2+Quad+Q9650+%40+3.00GHz ).

Any modern processor will be on a different socket and require a new motherboard. Unfortunately nowadays Intel changes sockets sufficiently often that upgrading the CPU on an existing motherboard is rarely worthwhile unless you bought a low-end cpu to start with.

* There was a third party hack that allowed use of some LGA771 processors in LGA775 sockets but it's not something i'd recommend to a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple factors playing into mainboard-CPU-compatibility -- the most notable are the **socket** (which is the connection interface between CPU and mainboard) and the **chipset** (which, stated in a very oversimplified way, is a processor on the mainboard that manages the communication between the CPU and everything else). A board with LGA 1200 cannot fit a CPU with LGA 775, and a chipset made for Intel's Coffee Lake (e.g. `ix-8xxx`) won't work with Intel's Kaby Lake (e.g. `ix-7xxx`) <sup>[[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1151#Second_revision_of_the_LGA_1151_socket_for_Coffee_Lake_CPUs)]</sup>. While socket compatibility is easy to check, chipset compatibility is a bit more obscure.

And as if that were not enough...certain chipsets get firmware updates for compatibility with other generations, but to get that firmware update, you typically need a BIOS/UEFI update -- so you are dependent on the mainboard manufacturer to release one.

---

If you have a mainboard and want to find out which CPUs are supported, you should look at the manufacturer's website and see if their support-site provides a compatibility sheet for your mainboard (most of them do). Certain CPUs might need a newer BIOS version, but usually, that's also stated (and provided).

If you want to buy both CPU and mainboard, things can get tricky. Here's two procedures I would suggest:

1. Pick a certain CPU, check its socket
2. Look for a mainboard you like that has the same socket
3. Check its support-website for a CPU compatibility sheet and see if
   the CPU is present.
4. If so, buy it. If not, you have to start again from point 2.

**Most of the time, if both CPU and mainboard have the same socket, then they are compatible. Though incompatibility with same sockets is somewhat rare, one should check for compatibility if one is unsure.**

If you just want any mainboard:

1. Pick a certain CPU
2. Most/all manufacturers provide tools to help you find a compatible mainboard: [Intel](http://processormatch.intel.com/) | [ASUS](https://www.asus.com/support/cpu_support) | [ASRock](http://www.asrock.com/support/cpu.de.asp) | [MSI](https://us.msi.com/support/motherboard/cpu-support/) | [Gigabyte](http://www.gigabyte.us/Support/CPU-Support) - other manufacturers might as well have such tools, just google `<YOUR_FAVOURITE_MANUFACTURER> CPU compatibility`.
3. Browse the compatible mainboards and pick your favourite.